# datagrid view change color depend of status in winform application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a function like this:

```
 Sub KPIColorchange()
        'take 80 percenatge
        Dim perc80 As Integer = 80
        value80 = DefaultKPI * perc80 / 100
        Dim carid As String
        Dim strr As String = "select t.TBarcode as carid from Khanger_tbl k 
               inner join transaction_tbl t on k.transactid=t.transactID"
        strr = strr + " where tid= " & tid & " and requested=1 and delivered=0  and status=3 
                and DATEDIFF(n, CAST(paydate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) >=" & value80 & ""
        Dim cmdr As New SqlCommand(strr, con.connect)
        dr2 = cmdr.ExecuteReader
        While dr2.Read
            If dr2("carid") Is DBNull.Value Then
                carid = ""
            Else
                carid = dr2("carid")
            End If

            Dim cnt As Integer = DGVall.Rows.Count
            For i = 0 To cnt - 2
                If DGVall.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString().Equals(carid) Then
                    DGVall.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia
                End If
            Next
        End While
        dr2.Close()
        con.disconnect()


        'take 100 percentage
        Dim perc100 As Integer = 100
        value100 = DefaultKPI * perc100 / 100

        Dim str100 As String = "select t.TBarcode as carid from Khanger_tbl k 
                 inner join transaction_tbl t on k.transactid=t.transactID"
        str100 = str100 + " where tid= " & tid & " and requested=1 and delivered=0  and status=3 and 
                DATEDIFF(n, CAST(paydate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) >=" & value100 & ""
        Dim cmd100 As New SqlCommand(str100, con.connect)
        dr2 = cmd100.ExecuteReader
        While dr2.Read
            If dr2("carid") Is DBNull.Value Then
                carid = ""
            Else
                carid = dr2("carid")
            End If

            Dim cnt As Integer = DGVall.Rows.Count
            For i = 0 To cnt - 2
                If DGVall.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString().Equals(carid) Then
                    DGVall.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
                End If
            Next
        End While
        dr2.Close()
        con.disconnect()
  End Sub
```

I have a grid view ,in that grid view i am loading some Requested carid we already set some time interval to Location.depend on the location time interval i have to change color in grid view

if the car requested time coming 80 percentage of location interval time then i will change to one color .
if the car requested time coming 100 percentage of location interval time then i will change to OrangeRed only this much things i am doing here..normally my datagrid view contains morethan 100 above records. this function i am calling in Timer_tick event in each one minute.
but becouse of this function my system get slow or some time system get hang.how i can optimize this code?
any help is very appreciable in advance

Comment: i can able to optimize this code?

Comment: if i set dataGridView.VirtualMode = true; this will help me?